# Can two site columns with same ID in two solutions, deployed to two site collections in same farm interfear?

Tags: 2013, solution-package, site-column

I have found a weird behavior of SP2013:

- I have 2 WSP solutions
- In each, there is elements.xml file containing site column. In both solutions, **ID and Name of columns is the same**. Site column is of type OutcomeChoice.
- Solutions are deployed to one farm.
- Feature of solution A is activated in site collection A
- Feature of solution B is activated in site collection B
- Column A in site collection A has its settings - in this case list of choices.
- **Column B in site collection B has settings (list of choices) from column A, even if in WSP are different values!!**

**Can anyone please explain me why and how to avoid this?** I would like both columns to have its own list of choices. So far I thought, site columns are isolated by site collections! But apparently they are not.

Comment: well, i suggest changing the ID (as well as Name/StaticName) for the site columns to help sharepoint differentiate between the two. because it seems that the site collections are isolated in terms of content but not necessarily in terms of used declarations. i guess this is the case because site columns are more likely provisioned to a site collection rather than 'saved' like list items, so sharepoint must be 'aware' of them at a web application(or farm) scope which obviously leads to conflicts.

Comment: @garglblarg thank you for your reply. I also considered this option. Problem is that I do not want to change IDs. I am in situation, where solutions are deployed at customer's environments - so changing IDs would cause new problems. Conflict occurs only in development farm, where both solutions are deployed - in customer's environment is always only one solution at time.

Comment: alright, since this is only causing shenanigans in the dev environment maybe a little experimentation is in order? if the solutions are deployed to the same web application i'd try to deploy them to different webapps and see if that works out, but that's just a hunch.

Comment: Consider using powershell to create and configure the site column.